# Is "increase their chance of being burgled" clear in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may be seen as easy targets and increase their chance of being burgled.

From 'and increase...' it sounds off to me. I tried changing it to 'and increasing' but that doesn't sound right either. Any suggestions?

Comment: *Robbed* rather than *burgled* is probably the word you want here: burglary is a crime which involves breaking into a building.

Comment: @StoneyB yes. Interestingly, prior to 1968 in Britain, in order for such breaking-in to constitute "burglary", it had to take place at night. Daytime break-ins were prosecuted as "breaking and entering" a lesser crime than "burglary". However nowadays it is "burglary" whatever time of the day or night it takes place.

Answer (score 1):

"Being burgled" means that someone breaks into your home, probably to steal things. Kids showing off their phones on the train increase their chance of being robbed, but not their chance of being burgled. "burgled" is clearly wrong here.

I don't like "their chance". "Chance" is more a positive thing. By buying two lottery tickets, you double your chances of winning. For being robbed, I would use "risk". "Chance" is not really wrong, but I think "risk" is slightly better.

Combining with what I think is the best of the other answers, I would say: "Children using mobile phones on public transport may be seen as easy targets which increases their risk of being robbed".

I have seen people using "improve" instead of "increase". If you used "chances of being robbed", then "increased" is not "improved", quite the opposite. So "improve their chances of being robbed" would be very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. I'd analyze it as follows.

First, take the initial phrase on its own:

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may...

And note that it is then ready for one or more items to bolt on after "may". One of them is:

> ...be seen as easy targets

giving:

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may **be seen as easy targets**.

And the other is:

> ...increase their chance of being burgled.

giving:

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may **increase their chance of being burgled**.

And since each on its own is fine, agreeing as they do with that initial portion, we can then simplify using a conjunction to get:

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may **be seen as easy targets** and **increase their chance of being burgled**.

The only thing I'd quibble with is the word *"burgled".* I'd have preferred if the original author had instead used, *"glared at by other passengers on the bus or train, possibly yelled at by the grumpier of said others, and generally regarded by all and sundry as delinquents whose obsession with their phones may well lead to the downfall of modern society and a return to a Hobbesian state of miserable nature."* But perhaps he felt that was a wee bit too wordy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly change your sentence to be more parallel sot hat both parts are hypothetical

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may be seen as easy targets and ***may*** increase their chance**s** of being burgled.

or

> Children using mobile phones on public transport ***are*** easy targets and increase their chance**s** of being burgled.

Comment: Grammar aside, I am puzzled by the sentence/s. Is *burglary* here being confused with mugging or pickpocketing? (Burglary, which means "forcible entry into a building especially at night with the intent to commit a crime https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burgle)

Comment: I think the OP intends "burgled" = "robbed", while usually a structure's, e.g. house's, contents are "burgled", I think we all know what is meant.

Comment: OP can only benefit by noting the difference - drummed into me as a young journalist.

Answer (score 0):

Well it "sounds" to me like it should be:

> Children using mobile phones on public transport may be seen as easy targets *which* **increases** their *chance(s)* of being burgled.

because if you equate "Children using mobile phones on public transport may be seen as easy targets" as a situation with "that", you could write:

> **(That situation) increases** their chance(s) of being burgled.

Also I would use *which* instead of *and* to tie together cause and result.